Physics of the duality transformation in electrodynamics
Jackson's Electrodynamics (3rd ed, Sec. 6.11) argues that one can
introduce magnetic charges and currents into the Maxwell equations
without changing observable physics:
For this, he introduces the duality transformation (6.151)
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E} & = \mathbf{E}' \cos\xi + Z_0\mathbf{H}' \sin\xi, &
  \mathbf{D} & = \mathbf{D}' \cos\xi + Z_0\mathbf{B}' \sin\xi, \\
  Z_0\mathbf{H}' & = - \mathbf{E}'\sin\xi + Z_0 \mathbf{H}'\cos\xi &
  Z_0\mathbf{B}' & = - \mathbf{D}'\sin\xi + Z_0 \mathbf{B}'\cos\xi &
\end{align}
$$
as a rotation $\xi$ in ($\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{H}$) space.  If
electric and magnetic charges and currents are rotated in the same
way, Eq. (6.152),
$$
\begin{align}
  Z_0 \rho_e & = Z_0 \rho_e' \cos\xi + \rho_m' \sin\xi, &
  Z_0 \mathbf{J}_e & = Z_0 \mathbf{J}_e' \cos\xi + \mathbf{J}_m' \sin\xi, \\
  \rho_m & = - Z_0 \rho_e'\sin\xi + \rho_m'\cos\xi &
  \mathbf{J}_m&  = - Z_0 \mathbf{J}_m' \sin\xi + \mathbf{J}_m'\cos\xi &
\end{align}
$$
(the impedance $Z_0 = \sqrt{\mu_0/\epsilon_0}$ ensures consistency
of prefactors), the extended Maxwell equations [Eq. (6.150)]
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{D} & = \rho_e, &
  \mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{H} & = \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t}
  + \mathbf{J}_e \\
  \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{B} & = \rho_m, &
 -\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{E} & = \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
  + \mathbf{J}_m
\end{align}
$$
are invariant under the rotations (6.151) and (6.152) (if performed
simultaneously), i.e., they describe the same observable physics.  So we can always find an angle $\xi$ such that we
have only electric charges.  Jackson argues: "The invariance of the
equations of electrodynamics under duality transformations shows
that it is a matter of convention to speak of a particle possessing
an electric charge, but not magnetic charge."
Later, starting from the field-strength tensor (11.137),
$$F^{\alpha\beta} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -E_x & - E_y & -E_z\\ E_x & 0 & - B_z & B_y \\ E_y & B_z & 0 & - B_x \\ E_z & - B_y & B_x & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
he introduces its dual (11.140),
$$\mathcal{F}^{\alpha\beta} 
= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} F_{\gamma\delta} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -B_x & -B_y & -B_z\\ B_x & 0 & E_z & -E_y \\ B_y & -E_z & 0 & E_x \\ B_z & E_y & -E_x & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
which allows him to bring the homogeneous Maxwell equations into the covariant form (11.142)
$$\partial_\alpha \mathcal{F}^{\alpha\beta} = 0.$$
My question is about Jackson's remark that the dual field-strength
tensor (11.140) was a "special case of the duality transformation
(6.151)." (page 556)  What does that mean?
Of course, as Jackson says (p556): "The elements of the dual tensor
$\mathcal{F}^{\alpha\beta}$ are obtained from $F^{\alpha\beta}$ by
putting $\mathbf{E} \rightarrow \mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{B}
\rightarrow -\mathbf{E}$ in (11.137)." And putting $\xi = \pi/2$ in
(6.151) does the same thing.  But my reading of the duality
transformation (6.151) is that we should do the same rotation in
(6.152).  Then, the duality transformation expresses an invariance
of observable physics [Eq. (6.150)] under $\xi$ rotations almost
like a gauge transformation.  All this is really a rather different
story from what happens in (11.140).  Then, using the same name for
this seems, at best, misleading.
Or am I trying to dig too deep?  Or is there something yet deeper that I am missing?
I know Sommerfeld's old geometric interpretation of the dual
field-strength tensor.  And I am also aware of question
37577.
But it seems to me that these discuss very different questions.  I
am concerned about the physical interpretation of the duality
transformation.

What happens in (6.151) when $\xi=\pi/2$?

As Jackson says (p556): "The elements of the dual tensor $\mathcal{F}^{\alpha\beta}$ are obtained from $F^{\alpha\beta}$ by putting $\mathbf{E} \rightarrow \mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{B} \rightarrow -\mathbf{E}$ in (11.137)." And yes, putting $\xi = \pi/2$ in (6.151) does the same thing.  My question: how/why is the latter relevant for getting the homogeneous Maxwell equations (11.142)?

Your first question was “In what sense discuss (6.151) and (11.140) related physical concepts?”, and I think you now understand that. It’s best to ask one question per post.

I really don’t understand what your second question is. Have you convinced yourself that (11.142) and (11.143) are in fact equivalent? If not, just write both in terms of $E_i$ and $B_i$.

I am sorry, I do not agree with your conjecture I would understand how (6.151) and (11.140) are related physical concepts.  The math of doing a $\pi/2$ rotation in (6.151) is trivial.  But in the context of (6.151), Jackson's physical interpretation of doing this rotation is that we effectively introduce magnetic charges into Maxwell's equations.  How is this relevant for bringing the homogeneous Maxwell equations into the covariant form (11.142)? -- Jackson suggests (6.151) and (11.140) are connected.  Is this connection just formal?

You’ve quoted Jackson as remarking that (11.140) is a special case of (6.151). There is nothing more to it than that, and there is nothing particularly physically significant about this special case other than that it is the most “extreme” form of duality where the fields completely swap their identities rather than “mixing”. I can’t be of further help since we seem to interpret Jackson differently. I hope that someone provides an actual answer (versus my few comments) that satisfies you.

It might help to put aside that book and study EM duality formulated with the help of the Hodge star operator. Then get back to Jackson an reconcile the two.
